# How can I compare two arrays and only return value that are true

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I'm tryng to compare two arrays containing time values. The goal is to return slots that are NOT at the time or in between two bookings, in a new array.

```
const bookings = ["2020-06-12T12:00:00.000Z", "2020-06-12T10:00:00.000Z"];
const slots = ["2020-06-12T11:00:00.000Z", "2020-06-12T12:20:00.000Z", "2020-06-12T13:40:00.000Z", "2020-06-12T15:00:00.000Z"];
```

This is my function to compare time values

```
const inBetween = (slot, existingBooking) => {
  const start = moment(slot);
  const end = moment(start).add(80, "m");
  existingBooking = moment(existingBooking).utc();
  //returns true or false
  return existingBooking.isBetween(start, end)
}
```

I am not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `filter` combined with `some`.

```
const availableSlots = slots.filter(s => !bookings.some(eb => inBetween(s, eb))
```

The `availableSlots` are the `slots` without some `existingBooking`.